# General Navier-Stokes equation set - Black box region boundary

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, fluid-dynamics

Consider the general (unsteady, compressible) Navier-Stokes equation (plus continuity and energy equations) for a newtonian fluid. No further peculiarities.

Suppose that a domain has been defined and that a solution exists and has been found meaning that one can give a value for the velocity (vector), pressure (scalar) and temperature (scalar) fields at each point in the domain space $\vec{x}$ at all times $t$.

Now subsequently suppose that a region inside the original domain is considered a black box with a certain boundary.

**Question:** Is it sufficient to set the original solution values as boundary conditions on the boundary of this black box to maintain the same, original solution in the rest of the domain? If yes, how can this fact be demonstrated with some mathematical rigor?

Please see a sketch of the situation to illustrate the question:

[Navier-Stokes domain with black box sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cGUv.png)

Comment: Anyone able to give some pointers here?

Comment: The answer is yes. There's nothing particularly special about NS in this regard, take any DE and you can split up the domain like this.

Comment: @David: Thank you for commenting. Could you provide some guidance on how I could prove this fact for general PDE's or point me to a text on this subject? I would gladly accept an answer providing some pointers. Is it relevant that unsteady, compressible NS is a system of PDEs and non-linear and not of specific (elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic) type?

Comment: I don't think you need anything except uniqueness, but I might be missing some technicalities. I don't think the specifics matter too much. I don't think I can help you with a rigorous explanation though.